# Alamofire for Swift 1.2 generates error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

After upgrading to the latest build of Xcode and downloading the newest Alamofire release, I am getting the following error:

> Module file was created by an older version of the compiler

With the previous version of Alamofire I added the entire AF project into my app as recommended, however the install guide for the latest version of AF says just to copy the .swift file into the project.

I am still calling `import Alamofire` in the file that requires it. This is also where the error appears. If I remove the `import` my project generates 86 additional errors.

Comment: It sometimes help in this case to do both cleaning operations in Xcode: menu Product => Clean, then the same with ALT key pressed to clean the folder.

Comment: I cleaned the build folder and now I get the following error on the `import Alamofire` line: > No such module 'Alamofire'

Comment: I just did the two cleanings, I have Alamofire installed with Cocoa Pods, in Xcode 6.3, and it works. I'm not sure what goes wrong here. :/

Comment: Interesting. Okay, thanks for your help. I'll keep troubleshooting. Trying to figure out how to setup Cocoa Pods for this project. I've got it installed, now just trying to figure out the rest.

Comment: Okay, so I got it done with CocoaPods and the Alamofire error goes away. That said, it brought 79 additional errors to light, but those are simple fixes based on updates done to the Swift language. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire is updated now for Xcode 6.3, until I know its creator merge the branch for Xcode 6.3 into the branch master in Github , you have to download it to correct the errors for the new Xcode.

But I strongly recommend you installing Alamofire using CocoaPods, I think is better, it's up to you.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks, however I am using Xcode 6.3 and I downloaded the Alamofire version for it. I will look into Cocoa Pods, but I doubt that will fix the issue. Thanks for trying to help, though! This is frustrating.

Comment: I use it Xcode 6.3 and I've installed using CocoaPods and it works fine.

Comment: Did you use it in a new project or in an existing project? I'm making a few tweaks to a project I deployed a month ago, and now I'm getting the error when replacing the old Alamofire with the new version.

Comment: @matcartmill I used it in a new project but I updated with the new version of Xcode 6.3 and it works fine.

Comment: I'll mark this as the right answer as once I started using CocoaPods the issue wasn't a problem anymore. However, it still doesn't explain why Alamofire's manual install didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

For me Cleaning up the Build folder <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> worked.